# How can I access Onedrive from within blender

Tags: file-browser

I keep all my documents etc. in Onedrive.  That way I have a copy on the PC and a copy in the cloud.

When using a "normal" windows file selector you are offered the choice of onedrive for all loading and saving.  Blender does not use this file selector and only sees old fashion drives.  Worse blender also ignores symbolic links so it is not possible to easily redirect to onedrive.

I can cheat by navigating to the onedrive cache, however this is mind numbing over time.

How do I get easy access to my files in onedrive from Blender?

Comment: There are scripts to map OneDrive to a lettered drive that should show up in Blender. See https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-onedrive-network-drive